# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/util/context/ContextView when using reactor-core and reactor-netty-http:1.0.9

Tags: netty, project-reactor, reactor-netty

Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/util/context/ContextView when using reactor-core 3.4.14 and reactor-netty-http:1.0.9 one the last line of code below. The version weems to be compatible and I can find the class when searchign for it in the IDE inside reactor-core lib

```
`        val client = WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(ReactorClientHttpConnector(reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.create().compress(true)))
            .build()

        val response = client.method(HttpMethod.GET)
            .uri(url)
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer $token")
            .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String::class.java)
            .block()`
```

this is how my build.gradle is

```
implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    exclude (group= "io.netty", module= "netty-codec-http")
    exclude (group= "io.netty", module= "netty-handler")
}
implementation ("io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:1.0.9")
implementation ("io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.4.14")
```

I'm trying to make the request using reactor lib to get a gzip response because the ransfer-encoding=[chunked]

Comment: Please make sure that you use Reactor BOM, thus Reactor Netty and Reactor Core versions will be always compatible. Also the versions that you are using are pretty old. https://github.com/reactor/reactor/releases

Comment: changed to versions below and getting same error on initalization now ->     implementation ("io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:1.1.8")
    implementation ("io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.5.4")